# Jquery disable a droppable after it has reached a limit of 3 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two list boxes that drag and drop I want my second list box to only allow 3 list items from the first list box. My problem is that when I reach the limit it does the counter works but I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'

and it allows it to drag more than 3 elements. I would like it to stop at 3 elements and when I drag out from the second list box it minus the counter.

```
var counter = 0;

$("#listbox2").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if (counter <= 3) {
            counter++;
            $('#counter_text').text(counter);
        }
        if (counter === 3) {
            $('#listbox2').droppable("disable");
            $('#listbox1 li').draggable("disable");
        }
    }
})

$("#listbox1").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        counter--;
        $('#counter_text').text(counter);

    }
})
```

Comment: `$('#listbox1 li').draggable("disable");` but in your posted code, you aren't initializing it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu simply have to initialize the draggable elements. This is a working sample (with an awful styling, BTW)

```js
var counter = 0;
$('#counter_text').text(counter);    

$('#listbox1 li').draggable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).css('left',0);
    $(this).css('top',0);
  }
});

$("#listbox2").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
    if (counter <= 3) {
      counter++;
      $('#counter_text').text(counter);
    }
    if (counter === 3) {
      $('#listbox2').droppable("disable");
      $('#listbox1 li').draggable("disable");
    }
  },
  hoverClass: 'hover'
});

$("#listbox1").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    counter--;
    if (counter<3) {
      $("li").draggable("enable");  
      $('#listbox2').droppable("enable");
    }
    $('#counter_text').text(counter);    
    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
    $(ui.draggable).draggable('enable');
  },
  hoverClass: 'hover'
});
```

```css
ul {
  border: solid 1px green;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 120px;
}

.hover {
  background-color: #CFC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="counter_text"></div>

<ul id="listbox1">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listbox2">
</ul>
```

Comment: When it reaches its limit is there a way to return the element from listbox2 back to listbox1 as you can see there is "counter --" to cater if element is returned.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your comment. Anyway, I'll try to answer: after dropping, you can change the "draggability" of the dropped object, depending on the parent. I.e. instead of disabling draggability of all the `li`, do it only if they belong to the 1st list.

Comment: You also need to modify the drop events to change the li parent, like this `$(this).append(ui.draggable);`

Comment: I've made changes in the code so that is more asthetic (set position to 0,0 on drop), and enables and disables drag/drop when necessary

Comment: Thanks for the example, issue am having, is when I drag the li positioning after dragging it is at the top left as you mentioned above. I would like the drag items to go in the second list box am using a "connectedSortable"

Comment: To make SO usable you shouldn't include new problems in comments to the original question. I think the first problem is solved. Please, state your new problem in a new question. Remember that you should add your current code (more exactly the bare minimum necessary part of your code to understand the problem), and explain which behavior you are expecting. For example say "If i drag an li from listbox1 to listbox2, when the element drops in the second list it should be ... but it ... instead". If you create that new question, add a new comment and I'll have a look. Or probably someone else.

Comment: Ok I will post a new question but I would first want to try " beforeStop:" method

Answer (score 1):

Check the execution flow of your progam : make sure that you have indeed initialized the plugin (e.g : called `$('#listbox1 li').draggable();`) before trying to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the drop function if you do:

```
 $('#list1').droppable("disable");
 $('#list2 li').draggable("disable");
```

You will get:

*Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'*

I will suggest you to do the same in timout funtion like this:

```
if ($('#list1 li').length >= 3) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          $('#list1').droppable("disable");
          $('#list2 li').draggable("disable");
        }, 100)
        return false;
      }
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/ampxsdbL/)